# Dynamodb: Ensure even read / write activity across partitions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The dynamodb docs say

> DynamoDB tables are distributed across multiple partitions. For best results, design your tables and applications so that read and write activity is spread evenly across all of the items in your tables

My question is if dynamodb automatically creates partitions how can I ensure that read / write activity is spread evenly? I have a table which has a primary key which consists of a guid.

Answer (score 0):

UUID have a uniform distribution so as long as you read each UUID the same amount relative to all the others, your load will be well spread out.